# Jmeter: Invalid uri escaped absolute path not valid

Tags: jmeter

Below are the steps I have followed:
1. Called HTTP Request in my script which generates a valid response in json. 
example:

> { "SortAs": "SGML", "GlossTerm": "2210", "Acronym": "SGML", "Abbrev":
>   "ISO 8879:1986" }

2. Now used Regular Expression Extractor to fetch a value from response (**"GlossTerm":(.+?)**) and added a user parameter (RNDM) that I have declared earlier like this: **${RNDM}.+"GlossTerm":(.+?)**

Here RNDM=90291 and GlossTerm=2210

The entire regex above is stored in Reference Name as **x**
3. I'm using the reference name to form my another url to call PUT method in a HTTP Request:
example: http://10.12.30.11/abc/test/${x}

When the script runs through the 3rd step I'm getting error as **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid uri 'http://10.12.30.11/abc/test/${x}': escaped absolute path not valid**

Debuggings that I have done yet:
1. Checked that the url doesn't has any space.
2. Tried with the url encoded form for special characters.

Having read through several of such posts in google, I come to post this query on stack overflow. Please help me in getting this issue solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression extractor is not correct, in particular it becomes incorrect when you add this `${RNDM}.` bit there. Moreover, it produces the next variables as it evidenced by the [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)

```
x="GlossTerm": "2210",
x_g=2
x_g0="GlossTerm": "2210", 
x_g1="GlossTerm": "2210",
x_g2= "2210",
```

[image: JMeter Debug Sampler]

Which doesn't seem to be something you're looking for.

So I would recommend doing the following:

1. Switch to [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor) which is more suitable for working with JSON data, the relevant [Json Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) query would be as simple as `$.GlossTerm`

   [image: JMeter JSON Path]
2. Amend your URL to look like: `http://10.12.30.11/abc/test/${RNDM}${x}`
3. That's it, you should get `http://10.12.30.11/abc/test/902912210` as the result:

   [image: JMeter Combine Variables]

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri. This worked for me. My script uses this url parameter: ${RNDM}${x} multiple times with different urls. So I would like to know how can I store it in a variable and reuse it later.